# MASM assembly - REAL4 float instructions

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, masm32

I'm trying to store float numbers in an array using a REAL4 data type. What are the correct instructions for the following?

1. Getting input from user and storing in an array? For example doing this but with a REAL4 number.

   ```
   mov array[ebx], sval(input())
   ```
2. Print float values. Another example,

   ```
   mov eax, array[ebx]
   print str$(eax)
   ```

Also if there are any links to a useful MASM real4 instruction documentation i would appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: There is no `print` instruction.  You have to call a function to print anything (or write the code to convert to a string yourself).  Note that `printf` only works with `double`, so you may want `cvtss2sd xmm1, array[ebx]`

Comment: @PeterCordes: `print` is a macro included in the MASM32 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A REAL4 number is just a bunch of 32 bits like DWORD, but interpreted in a different way. If you don't need the special MASM options and checks for REAL4 you can also use the MASM types DWORD resp. SDWORD or the common assembler type DD.

For the most external functions you have to convert a REAL4 number (Single-precision floating-point format) to a a REAL8 number (Double-precision floating-point format). The easiest way is to load the single into the FPU and store it as double.

The input from console will be stored as a string. You have to convert this string into the desired format.

Let's first output an array of REAL4 numbers:

```
INCLUDE \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.DATA
    result  REAL8 0.0
    array   REAL4 -1.0, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.567, 0.0
            SDWORD -1               ; End of array -> NaN

.CODE
main PROC
    xor ebx, ebx

    @@:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR array[ebx]   ; "DWORD PTR" = "REAL4 PTR"
    cmp eax, -1                     ; NaN = end of array?
    je @F                           ; Yes -> Jump to the next @@

    fld DWORD PTR array[ebx]        ; Load a single into FPU ...
    fstp QWORD PTR result           ; ... and store it as double
    printf("%f\n",result)           ; MASM32 macro that acts like the C function

    add ebx, 4                      ; REAL4 has 4 bytes
    jmp @B                          ; Jump to the previous @@

    @@:
    exit 0

main ENDP

END main
```

Now let's input a couple of numbers and print them. There is place for 16 variables. The program doesn't check that limit. You end the input by typing just ENTER (without a number):

```
INCLUDE \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
INCLUDE \masm32\macros\macros.asm

.DATA
    result  REAL8 0.0
    lpstring DWORD 0
    array   REAL4 16 DUP (0.0)
            SDWORD -1                           ; End of array -> NaN

.CODE
main PROC

    xor ebx, ebx

    @@:
    mov esi, input("Enter number here ",62," ") ; Input string ... STRING!
    cmp BYTE PTR [esi], 0;                      ; Nothing inputted?
    je @F                                       ; Yes -> jump forward to the next @@

    push ebx                                    ; StrToFloat changes EBX! So it is to save
    INVOKE StrToFloat, esi, ADDR result         ; Convert string to double
    pop ebx                                     ; Restore the saved EBX

    fld REAL8 PTR result                        ; Load a double ...
    fstp REAL4 PTR array[ebx]                   ; ... and save it as single
    mov eax, -1                                 ; NaN = end of array
    mov DWORD PTR array[ebx+4], eax             ; Store the NaN as the next element

    add ebx, 4                                  ; Pointer to the next REAL4 in array
    jmp @B                                      ; Jump back to the previous @@

    @@:
    xor ebx, ebx

    @@:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR array[ebx]               ; "DWORD PTR" = "REAL4 PTR"
    cmp eax, -1                                 ; NaN = end of array?
    je @F                                       ; Yes -> Jump to the next @@

    fld DWORD PTR array[ebx]                    ; Load a single into FPU ...
    fstp QWORD PTR result                       ; ... and store it as double
    printf("%f\n",result)                       ; MASM32 macro that acts like the C function

    add ebx, 4                                  ; REAL4 has 4 bytes
    jmp @B                                      ; Jump to the previous @@

    @@:

    exit 0

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: You only have to convert to `double` for variadic functions.  Most C library math functions have an `f`-suffix version that take and return a `float`.  e.g. `sqrtf`, `sinf`, `atan2f`.  I'm assuming that MSVC's standard library provides these.  Also, I wouldn't recommend using / learning x87 first .  Even in 32-bit code, it's pretty common to assume support for SSE / SSE2.  You only need to use x87 if you use a calling convention that returns FP values in `st(0)`.